# 3d triangle gets stuck c++ opengl glfw

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glfw

im trying to make a 3d triangle spin and it gets stuck because it doesnt go into one of my if's and i dont know why its not going into it.
in thoery it should work but it just stops after one spin
can someone help?
[this is where it stops spining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgmkZ.png)

```
void Triangle::turnLeft(Triangle* t)
{

    if (pointGoLeft1 && p1.getX() < 0.5f)
    {
        p1.increaseX();
    }
    else if (p1.getX() == 0.5f && pointGoLeft1)
    {
        pointGoLeft1 = false;
    }
    else if (p1.getX() == -0.5f && !pointGoLeft1)
    {
        pointGoLeft1 = true;
    }
    else if (!pointGoLeft1 && p1.getX() > -0.5f)
    {
        p1.decreaseX();
    }

    if (pointGoLeft3 && p3.getX() < 0.5f)
    {
        p3.increaseX();
    }
    else if (p3.getX() == 0.5f && pointGoLeft3)
    {
        pointGoLeft3 = false;
    }
    else if (p3.getX() == -0.5f && !pointGoLeft3)
    {
        pointGoLeft3 = true;
    }
    else if (!pointGoLeft3 && p3.getX() > -0.5f)
    {
        p3.decreaseX();
    }

    if (pointGoLeft4 && p4.getX() < 0.5f)
    {
        p4.increaseX();
    }
    else if (p4.getX() == 0.5f && pointGoLeft4)
    {
        pointGoLeft4 = false;
    }
    else if (p4.getX() == -0.5f && !pointGoLeft4)
    {
        pointGoLeft4 = true;
    }
    else if (!pointGoLeft4 && p4.getX() > -0.5f)
    {
        p4.decreaseX();
    }

    t->buildTriangle();
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good point to introduce a debugger. Once your triangle gets stuck, break into the debugger and step through the `turnLeft` method. It should always follow the same path and give you a clue what is going wrong.